# Better way to do this figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have done a figure for some lecture notes. I am sure that it is not a very nice code. So my question is: Could this has been done in a better way, for instance by using `pgfplots`?

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% coordinate axis
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[below left] {$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0,-6) node[below left] {$y$};

\newcommand{\ang}{-30}

% dashed line
\draw[dashed]  (0,0) coordinate (s)-- ++ (\ang:4) coordinate (d1) ;

\draw[-] (d1) --++ (1.7,0) ;

\begin{scope} [rotate=\ang]
    \draw [fill = blue!30, draw = black] (d1) rectangle ++ (1,-.6);      
    \draw[-latex] (d1) --++ (2,0) node[below left] {$V_x$};
    \draw[-latex] (d1) --++ (0,-1.5) node[below left] {$V_y$};
    \draw[latex-latex] (5.5,0) arc (0:30:1.5)  node[below right] {$\varphi$};;
    \draw[-latex] (4.8,1) arc (45:-45:1.5) node[below left] {$\omega$};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

UPDATE
I have now updated the code with the helpful pointers from @Sebglav

````
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes, arrows.meta, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% coordinate axis
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[below left] {$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0,-6) node[below left] {$y$};

\newcommand{\ang}{-30}

% dashed line
\draw[dashed]  (0,0) coordinate (s)-- ++ (\ang:4) coordinate (B) ;

\draw[-] (B) --++ (1.7,0)  coordinate (C);

\begin{scope} [rotate=\ang]
    \draw [fill = blue!30, draw = black] (B) rectangle ++ (1,-.6);      
    \draw[-latex] (B) --++ (2,0) node[below left] {$V_x$};
    \draw[-latex] (B) --++ (0,-1.5) node[below left] {$V_y$};
    
    \draw (5.5,0) coordinate (A) -- (B) -- (C)
            pic ["$\varphi$", draw, angle eccentricity=1.2, latex-latex, angle radius=1.5cm] {angle};

    \draw[-latex] (4.8,1) arc (45:-45:1.5) node[below left] {$\omega$};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}```
````

Comment: Why would you bother to try and do it with pgfplots when you already done it in Ti*k*Z in a very satisfaying manner? You could take advantage of the `angles` and `quotes` libraries, especially to draw you `varphi` angle, but apart from that...

Comment: Thanks! I have added the updated code above using ```angles``` and ```quotes```.

Comment: Looks good, but I would shorten the y-axis.

Comment: This is more like a diagram than a plot/graph, so no need to use PGFPlots. Only reason to use PGFPlots is if you have other plots/graphs in your document and you wish to keep a consistent axis style.